# GSS-API Kerberos Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos, spnego, gssapi

Im trying to create a application that can authenticate a user using kerberos ticket. I dont know how can i proceed with this. i have wrote some code to get spengo token from header and then extract the kerberos token from it. but i receive only a null spengo token. im running my application on the same server that the active directory is set up.

here is the method that im using to get spnego token

```
private byte[] getSPNEGOTokenFromHTTPRequest(HttpServletRequest req) {

    byte[] spnegoToken = null;

    if (req != null) {

        String header = req.getHeader("Authorization");

        if ((header != null) && header.startsWith("Negotiate")) {

            header = header.substring("Negotiate".length()).trim();

            try {
                spnegoToken = Base64.decode(header);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //todo
            }
        }
    }
    return spnegoToken;
}
```

Can any one help me with this or tell me what im doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste your time, use libraries: http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/